# No audio devices found, no proper sound

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, system-settings

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04** on **Dell Vostro 15** laptop. The *Sound Settings* surprisingly doesn't find any audio device. Here is a screenshot:

[image: no audio devices found in System settings-> sound]

Here are the outputs of :-

`lspci -nnk | grep -A3 Audio`

```
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Dell Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [1028:065c]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC [8086:9c31] (rev 04)
--
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell 8 Series HD Audio Controller [1028:065c]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:9c10] (rev e4)
```

`aplay -l`

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3234 Analog [ALC3234 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`sudo pactl list short sinks`

```
Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/0/snap.pulseaudio/pulse): No such file or directory
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
```

Because of this reason, I can't use any driver for sound. It is always mute.

What to do ???

Comment: 16.04 is somewhat old. Are you sure it supports your audio device? Have you tried a newer Ubuntu in Live mode?

Comment: And there have been recent changes to pulseaudio that have caused people problems.  I am guessing they will fix them soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options in here https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html. Option #1 worked for me when I had a similar issue in 19.10.

Comment: This didn't work for me . I tried both options given there.

Comment: Is there some other way ???

Comment: Actually, I have recently upgraded my PC to Ubuntu 18.04, so I have edited my question.

Comment: Try reinstalling pulseaudio and make sure it actually starts by running

pulseaudio --start